# Flutter - FCM: how to store background message to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a notification system for my mobile application, the idea is to store both foreground and background messages received from Firebase Cloud message to SQLite. I've followed the [guideline](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) here to set up my project.

Here my code:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    service = MySQLService();

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        service.insertItem(Item.fromMessage(message)); // It's working, here.
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );

    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      print("Push Messaging token: $token");
    });
}
```

And the code for handling background message:

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print("onBackground: $message");
  var service = MySQLService();
  await service.insertItem(Item.fromMessage(message)); // It's not working, here.
  return Future<void>.value();
}
```

For now, my application can: receive foreground message and store it into SQLite (by calling **service.insertItem**), But for some reason, background message is not stored in the SQLite even it displayed on the notification list of the device.

[image]

UPDATE: here the code for inserting message

```
  Future<void> insertItem(Item notification) async {
    final Database db = await MyDatabase.getDatabase();
    await db.insert('notification', notification.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

Comment: Is the problem in iOS or Android or both? Could you share the code of MySQLService? Maybe you are not starting the service the right way? Take a look at this package, https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite , its suppose to do DB tasks in the background.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with my inserting function because it's working in case of foreground message. Only background message is not inserted. Maybe the **onBackgroundMessageHangler** didn't call from the start, can't say for sure because I don't know how to debug in the background.

Comment: I think you can still somehow debug even if your app is closed. If your android phone for example is connected to your machine and a message is received in the background this will be executed `print("onBackground: $message");` so check the log in your IDE. I think i have tried this once in Android IDE. If you notice your phone will still be logging so many things from different apps if its connected.

Comment: When I asked if this doesn't work in Android or iOS due to the way you start the service, I had  in mind the information in this page. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite#3-open-the-database. But like you said I guess if it worked in the foreground it must work in the background: the path is already correctly set.

Comment: As far as I can tell `print("onBackground: $message");` is not called. My emulator does receive the message, but nothing is logged on the debug console.

Comment: have you found a solution? The code in background seens not be trigered.. And i didnt find a way to debug precisily this.

Comment: I found some random comment on github stated that this is a bug and it hasn't fixed yet. So I decide to store information on the cloud (Firebase database) instead of SQLite.

Comment: I insert into mysql       when the app s in the background but NOT when terminated. Help

Comment: I didn't found any solution for SQLite nor MySQL, if you are still in trouble then post your own question.

Comment: I'm also having difficulty background messages to save in sqlite database using sqflite plugin. I searched so many topics about this problem but people is still having difficulties. `onBackgroundMessage` not firing when you have background messages.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `onBackgroundMessage` is only called when the FCM message does not contain a `notification` (e.g. is a pure data message). Messages like that will of cause not trigger a notification on the device by default.

What I ended up doing is only send data messages (to be able to catch them in background) and handle the notification part on the device myself with the [flutter_local_modifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) packages.

```
// TOP-LEVEL or STATIC function to handle background messages
static Future<dynamic> onBackgroundMessage(
    Map<String, dynamic> notification) async {

  var msg;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    msg = notification['data'];
  } else {
    msg = notification;
  }

  DatabaseService _dbService = DatabaseService();
  msg = await _dbService.insertMessage(msg);
  _showNotification(msg);
  return Future<void>.value();
}

static Future _showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
  // TODO: Use a proper channel
  var platformChannelSpecificsAndroid = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High);
  var platformChannelSpecificsIos =
      IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: true);
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      platformChannelSpecificsAndroid, platformChannelSpecificsIos);

  return Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      "some id",
      msg["title"],
      msg["body"],
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: "some id",
    );
  });
}
```

For this to work, all involved plugins must be registered early like described below "*By default background messaging is not enabled. To handle messages in the background*" in [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging).

Trying to translate what is written there to a kotlin project I ended up creating a file *<app_name>/android/app/src/main/kotlin/<app_uri>/Application.kt* that registers the plugins, like:

```
package <your package>

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin

public class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(
                registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))

        com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin.registerWith(
                registry.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"))

        com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(
                registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"))
    }
}
```